# Add commas into numerical output in C? (i.e., output is $12345.67, need it to be 12,345.67)

Tags: c

When outputting a number, it needs to be split every 3 numbers with a comma. I can't use any advanced techniques or add additional libraries/use arrays and whatnot, just super simple stuff since our prof hasn't taught us that stuff yet.

Is there a way to do this using modulus division? I've been trying for awhile :(

```
#include <stdio.h>

   /* Define Tax rates per range */

   #define TAX_RATE_COLUMN1 .15
   #define TAX_RATE_COLUMN2 .22
   #define TAX_RATE_COLUMN3 .26
   #define TAX_RATE_COLUMN4 .29

   /* Define base amounts that are substracted from the taxable income per range*/

   #define BASE_AMOUNT_COLUMN1 40970.00
   #define BASE_AMOUNT_COLUMN2 81941.00
   #define BASE_AMOUNT_COLUMN3 127021.00

   /* Define tax on the base amount per range */

   #define TAX_BASE_AMOUNT_COLUMN1 6146.00
   #define TAX_BASE_AMOUNT_COLUMN2 15159.00
   #define TAX_BASE_AMOUNT_COLUMN3 26880.00

main()
{

   /* Variable declaration as floats */

   float federalTax, taxableIncome; 

    printf("~~~ Canadian Federal Tax Calculation for 2010 ~~~\n");
    printf("Enter Taxable Income ==> ");
    scanf("%f", &taxableIncome);

   /* Statements to calculate the federal tax on taxable income based on the 
   range of the users input */

    if (taxableIncome < 0) {
       printf("ERROR: Taxable Income cannot be negative.\n");
       }
    else if (taxableIncome >=0 && taxableIncome <=40970) {
       taxableIncome = taxableIncome * TAX_RATE_COLUMN1;
       federalTax = taxableIncome;
       printf("Federal Tax is $%.2f\n", federalTax);
       }
    else if (taxableIncome > 40970 && taxableIncome < 81941) {
       taxableIncome = taxableIncome - BASE_AMOUNT_COLUMN1;
       taxableIncome = taxableIncome * TAX_RATE_COLUMN2;
       taxableIncome = taxableIncome + TAX_BASE_AMOUNT_COLUMN1;
       federalTax = taxableIncome;
       printf("Federal Tax is $%.2f\n", federalTax);
       }
    else if (taxableIncome >= 81941 && taxableIncome <= 127021) {
       taxableIncome = taxableIncome - BASE_AMOUNT_COLUMN2;
       taxableIncome = taxableIncome * TAX_RATE_COLUMN3;
       taxableIncome = taxableIncome + TAX_BASE_AMOUNT_COLUMN2;
       federalTax = taxableIncome;
       printf("Federal Tax is $%.2f\n", federalTax);
       }
    else if (taxableIncome > 127022) {
       taxableIncome = taxableIncome - BASE_AMOUNT_COLUMN3;
       taxableIncome = taxableIncome * TAX_RATE_COLUMN4;
       taxableIncome = taxableIncome + TAX_BASE_AMOUNT_COLUMN3;
       federalTax = taxableIncome;
       printf("Federal Tax is $%.2f\n", federalTax);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add back the statement required in the code that this is entirely your own work, although you can blank out the name of the college if you'd like.

Comment: It would be worth explaining why floats are such a bad idea for currency.

Comment: Tip: 1+ log10(value) returns the number of digits before the decimal point in the decimal representation of value (assuming it is > 0).

Comment: there's not much use posting the code you've posted, your question is obvious enough without it. If you want to show some code, post some attempts you've made.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be to convert it to a string ( Im assuming commas are when your showing the numbers to the user.)

Basicly you do it this way:
1) Convert the number to a string.
2) Simple loop over the string and insert a comma's pr 3 char.

Comment: We haven't learnt about string conversion, so we get marks off for using it.

Answer (score 1):

Forget C and try to do it with maths.

I see you've tried to use the modulus operator - that gives the remainder. How would you get the remainder of 10/6 if you didn't have the modulus operator?

Given a number 12345, how do you "extract" just the last digit (the 5)?

How do you extract the last 3 digits, 345?

How do you extract the first 2 digits, 12?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, for simplicity, that only one comma is needed, *i.e.*, no values above $999,999.99.

Next, let’s split this into the integer and fractional part:

```
float value = 123456.75f;
int integer_part = (int) value;
float fractional_part = value - integer_part;
```

Now to inset commas:  `integer_part % 1000` will yield 456; `integer_part / 1000` will yield 123; `fractional_part` will be 0.75.

Translating this into code is your assignment.

Comment: Thanks so much, will be doing this, got it! Thanks.

Comment: Then please click accecpt on his reply :)

Comment: Im not a registered user, not sure how.

Comment: Should be a symbol like a V ( That turns green ) by the arrows up and down on his reply

Answer (score 0):

When you use printf, you should use `$%,.2f`

Notice the comma that I have added. Hopefully it does not count as an advanced technique because you are already using printf

Comment: I believe that is not technically standard C, but it is in fact a POSIX extension?